# Delete records from a recordset containing excel rows

Tags: vbscript

**Okay! Directly into the code then!**

> *Code :*

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H0001

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\HV\Desktop\samp.xls;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";" 

objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", _
objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

objRecordSet.delete 1
```

> *Error Message :*

http://s14.postimage.org/fntmbde0x/err.jpg

> *XLS :*

http://s7.postimage.org/4oklf867f/xls.jpg

**What I expect to do is to just delete the 1st record from the record set, remember only the record set not update into the XLS. Any help is greatly appreciated :)**

Answer (score 0):

You need a disconnected recordset.

1. Set `Recordset.CursorLocation` to `adUseClient`
2. Open the recordset & fetch rows
3. Set `Recordset.ActiveConnection` to `Nothing`.

Now you can delete records from recordset.

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1
Const adUseClient = 3
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\samp.xls;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
objRecordSet.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objRecordSet.Open "Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
Set objRecordSet.ActiveConnection = Nothing
objConnection.Close
objRecordSet.Delete 1
```